# Using c++ covariance to derive an object's sub type

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance

The following code generates an object of sub type as expected, but its default cast is as a super pointer to the sub object.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
class super {
    virtual super* get_clone() = 0;
}
class subA : super {
    sub* get_clone() { return new subA(); };
}
class subB : super {
    sub* get_clone() { return new subB(); };
}

subA a;
super *s = &a;
```

Now if I run s->get_clone() in gdb, I get:

`(gdb) p s->get_clone()
(super *)0x7fff7c`

I don't understand why it returns a (super *) pointer instead of a (subA *) pointer.  I realized I could just cast the pointer, but I was trying to create templated code based off the returned sub type.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a typo that your functions return a pointer to the undefined type `sub`?

Comment: "but I was trying to create templated code based off the returned sub type." Wait, you're trying to determine at compile time the type that will be returned at runtime? There's no way that could ever work. It's not known at compile time that `s` will always point to a `subA` object. You'll need to give a lot more details about what you're really trying to accomplish, because what you're asking for is just plain impossible, but there's almost certainly something that gets close enough to what you're asking for that *is* possible.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot know what is the actual concrete class of the object that the pointer will be pointing at runtime. It only knows that the pointer will point to an instance of subclass of s.

```
class super 
{
    public:
    virtual super* get_clone() = 0;
};

class subA : public super 
{
    public:
    subA* get_clone()
    {
        std::cout << "subA::get_clone()\n";
        return new subA();
    };
};

class subB : public super 
{
    public:
    subB* get_clone()
    {
        std::cout << "subB::get_clone()\n";
        return new subB();
    };
};

int main()
{
    subA a;
    super *s1 = &a;
    super* s2 = s1->get_clone();
    //subA* s3 = s1->get_clone();  // compile error here; the compiler doesn't know what is the concrete class s points to.

    subA* a1 = &a;
    subA* a2 = a1->get_clone();  // here it can know that the returned pointer is to subA.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What `gdb` has reported is correct. It is reporting the return type for the method you invoked. Even though the implementation of the virtual method has a different return type, the return value is "converted" to the return type that is returned by the method you invoked.

As has been pointed out in comments, the dynamic binding nature of the virtual method `get_clone()` is not amenable to a static binding use-case. Any static binding you may want to do can be done within the sub-types, interfaced through *super*. One technique you could use to achieve that would be a kind of CRTP style template function provided by *super*:

```
class super {
    virtual super * get_clone () = 0;
protected:
    template <typename SUB> SUB * get_clone_common (SUB *) {
        //...
        return new SUB;
    }
};

class subA : super {
    subA * get_clone () { return get_clone_common(this); }
};
```

In the above example, `subA` performs the static binding through the template interface provided by `super`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the fact that covariance using virtual only amounts to dynamic binding, which is not enough to overcome a static binding.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  But I tried your suggestion to use CRTP to cast the return value from super, and I'm still running into trouble..  Basically, I gdb inside of get_clone, and the return type of get_clone_common is (subA*), but the return type of get_clone() is still (super*).  Its seems like CRPT still won't change the static cast from the original (super) pointer.

Comment: `super::get_clone()` will always result in a `super *`, because that is what the code says it will return. The template stuff happens inside of `get_clone_common`.